# How to deploy JavaFx Application with Gradle

Tags: gradle, javafx

Hi I'm trying to deploy a JavaFX Gradle Application.

I can run the Application with the following VM Options by opening the gradle window in intelliJ and click run

VM Options:

```
--module-path /Users/$USER/development/javafx-sdk-16/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

But when I try to deploythe Application to an executable Jar it tells me `The JAVA JAR *.jar could not be launched`

I already checked the console for error Messages but could not find any.

This is my gradle.build:

```
plugins {
id 'application'
id 'com.dua3.javafxgradle7plugin' version '0.0.9'
id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
}


repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

jar {
manifest {
    attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'org.me.Main'
    )
}
}

javafx {
version = "16"
modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = 'org.me.Main'
sourceCompatibility = 16
targetCompatibility = 16
version = '1.0'


dependencies {
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.12"
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
}
```

Running the JAR file from Terminal via `java -jar App.jar` gives me the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
at org.me.Main.main(Main.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 10 more
```

I did include a `module-info.java` under main/java with the following content:

```
module speedtestGradleRx {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires io.reactivex.rxjava3;
requires org.apache.commons.io;

opens org.me to javafx.fxml;
exports org.me;
}
```

And I added an extra Main.java which does not extend Application, with the following content:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainApp.main(args);

}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to launch it using the same VM parameters? Like `java -jar App.jar --module-path /Users/$USER/development/javafx-sdk-16/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Comment: I just tried, but it does not work.

Comment: and in this order: `java --module-path /Users/$USER/development/javafx-sdk-16/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar App.jar` ?

Comment: Does not work either, but i get another exception: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/SingleObserver so this maybe solves the main issue

Comment: Well you should add `rxjava` module to path

Comment: Means download rxjava and add like javafx in the command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231978/discussion-between-midi-and-alex).